# Links to external documents alfresco

Tags: hyperlink, external, alfresco, dashlet, electronic-direct-mail

we've got to implement a document repository with Alfresco and is required that links to external documents (they could be an Url or a network uri like \SERVER\doc.pdf) should be available as regular alfresco-stored documents (tag, categorize and comment them).

I'm wondering whether it's possible to do that with Alfresco or we are going to develop that functionality ourselves.

Comment: Can you store them as Links? Links can be tagged, categorised etc

Comment: Actually, we need them to be displayed as documents, I mean like the library for the UI experience, that's I'm looking for anything else than Links. Tks!

Comment: You would have to develope your own functionality in that case because out of box no features avilable which you could use to achive that.

Comment: It would be *a lot* of work to implement a customisation for this in Alfresco. Thumbnails, previews, indexing etc all rely on a physical document being present in the contentstore. You're much better off ingesting the document.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve this with [Alfresco Bulk File System Import](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/concepts/bulk-import-in-place.html), which will allow you to load all the files from where they reside, into the Alfresco content store. In addition to that, you can use the [Alfresco Content Stores](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/concepts/manage-cs-home.html) to manage multiple content stores within Alfresco.

Comment: Links can be helpful as supplemental information, but [link-only answers are strongly discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/228805). Please include a summary of the linked information that's relevant to the question, and explain how it resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple HTML document with a javascript redirect inside like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
// ]]></script>
```

Save it as something.html and upload in Alfresco.